# ion tabs doesn't show correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 and I need a tab menu with 2 choices which, when clicked, send the user to the relative page.
This is what I've done:

**tabsexample.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root">First Page Tab</ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root">Second Page Tab</ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

I generated the relative pages and **`tabsexample.ts`** is like this:

```
import {FirstPage} from '../first-page/first-page';
import {SecondPage} from '../second-page/second-page';
export class tabsexamplePage {

  tab1Root = FirstPage;
  tab2Root = SecondPage;
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
```

What I get is a white bar without the tab text (`First Page Tab` and `Second Page Tab`). Moreover the 2 tabs fill the entire width of the screen so the second tab is below the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root">First Page Tab</ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root">Second Page Tab</ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

Just include the `ion-tabs` element but without the `ion-content` wrapper:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root">First Page Tab</ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root">Second Page Tab</ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```